# sending sms using textbelt api not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have a scenario where i need to send sms through my application for that i am using textbelt api service but its giving me error saying cannot read the property 'length of undefined'

I m using express.js framework

Controller code:

```
var text = require('textbelt');

exports.sendSms = function(req, res) {
    var opts = {
        fromAddr: 'sthakur@innominds.com', // "from" address in received text
        fromName: 'shikha', // "from" name in received text
        region: 'india', // region the receiving number is in: 'us', 'canada', 'intl'
        subject: 'something' // subject of the message
    }

    text.sendText('9032400119', 'A sample text message!',opts);
};
```

and routing part:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./sms.controller');

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/sendSms', controller.sendSms);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.patch('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

I dont have any idea why that error is coming

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Could you provide the actual error?

Comment: Do note that you're not actually sending a response back in your controller. Secondly you're implementing `sendText` in a seemingly synchronous way, which is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE:**

I tried by giving region as us and i get the log

This is what i tried, for which i get  'SMS SENT' log in my console, but SMS is not being sent .

```
var opts = {
                    fromAddr: '%s@email.uscc.net', // "from" address in received text
                    fromName: 'User', // "from" name in received text
                    region: 'us', // region the receiving number is in: 'us', 'canada', 'intl'
                    subject: 'Test SMS' // subject of the message
                }

                text.sendText('82*****', 'A sample text message!', opts);
                console.log(opts)
                console.log('SMS SENT')
```

Comment: Can you please tell why this is not the answer to the question...i tried it removing the region param, where i could see the logs...so asked him to try the same, if it may work...!!!